# How can I download Android source code

Tags: android

I cannnot vist this site:[android.git.kernel.org](http://android.git.kernel.org),where else can I get Android source code?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/android ??

Comment: you do not visit `android.git.kernel.org` from your browser. You need to use a version control system to get it. Here are the instructions: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: Hi Sarwar,I do excute curl https://android.git.kernel.org/repo > ~/bin/repo,but there no response from that site

Comment: @Jake: You can also read the entire Android source code here https://zgrepcode.com/android

Answer (score 3):

There's a mirror over @ github.

https://github.com/android/

Comment: thanks Jens.but the code is divided into many parts,how can i download the full package?thank u

Comment: Source code is no more available on the Github link.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the source on hand for reference there are two very useful Eclipse plugins which complement the SDK and keep Android source up-to-date and correspondent to the target version of your project:

http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update
 http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/binedit/com.android.ide.eclipse.binedit.update

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the source code for linux/mac is easy using the Google's instructions on http://source.android.com/

But, using Windows I did this by using Ubuntu live CD, and downloading all the source code using the linux instructions.

There are some commands you need to use for the code to be downloaded to your main hardrive. I wrote a blog post about it here: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/the-source-for-all-goodness/

Answer (score 0):

The official github mirror seems to be at [aosp-mirror](https://github.com/aosp-mirror) now

More info about structure: [here](https://aosp-mirror.github.io/)